# How do you ask "How + adjective" questions in Latin, such as "how big is your house?", "how large was Caesar's army"?

Tags: interrogative

Many students who want to practice spoken Latin come up with questions starting with "How + adjective": how large? how big? how important?. Is there a short way to ask those questions or is paraphrasing needed?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to modify the adjective with *quam*, "to what degree?". Formally, this is an *interrogative adverb*, that asks a question about how the adjective should be modified.

I couldn't find a direct question in my quick search (annoyingly, the PHI corpus doesn't let me search for question marks) but here's an indirect one from Cicero's defense of Quintus Roscius Amerinus:

> **Quam sīs audāx** omnēs intellegere potuērunt.
> *Everyone could tell **how brave you were**.*

Comment: But for "how big/large," would we not usually use *quantus*? Would it be right to say "Quanta est domus tua?" or "Quantus exercitus Caesaris erat?" (Serious question. I cannot recall seeing *quantus* in simple *est* statements or questions, but I also couldn't say what's wrong with it or how else to phrase it, aside from *quam magnus*.)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I generally think of _quantus_ as asking about quantity, not quality, so I would say _quam magnus_, but I'll have to do a corpus search later to check this. (Or perhaps ask another question.)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel & Draconis: This line from Plautus' *Rudens* might be of interest: "Labr. Quam magnum vero? Daem. Quantum lenoni sat est." Compare that to Cicero's "Immo vero quantus exercitus!"

Comment: @Draconis: In "quam sis audax" why "sis" and not "es"/ "eras"? Doesn't the present subjunctive imply some doubt--how brave you may be?

Comment: @tony Indirect question